# Display Tags of Child Pages

Tags: child-pages, tags

I'm trying to display tags of child pages on the parent page.

In my functions.php:

```
// add tag support to pages
function tags_support_all() {
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page');
}

// ensure all tags are included in queries
function tags_support_query($wp_query) {
if ($wp_query->get('tag')) $wp_query->set('post_type', 'any');
}

// tag hooks
add_action('init', 'tags_support_all');
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tags_support_query');
```

In my page template:

```
<div id="masonry-loop" class = "group"> 
<?php

$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order');
$count = 0;
foreach($pages as $page)
{
    $content = $page->post_content;
    $images = get_field('gallery', $page->ID);
    $thumbnail = $images[0];

?>

<div class="artist_thumb">
    <div class="artist_thumb_img"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail['url'] ?>"/></a></div>
    <h3><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?> "target="_blank"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h3>
    <p><?php echo $page->post_tag ?></p>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

This displays the thumbnails and titles of the child pages, but not the tags. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code based on this posting's answer, and the page displays everything I want now.

```
<div id="masonry-loop" class = "group"> 
<?php
global $post;
$child_pages_query_args = array(
'post_type'   => 'page',
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);

$child_pages = new WP_Query( $child_pages_query_args );

if ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post(); ?>

<?php $images = get_field('gallery'); $thumbnail = $images[0]; ?>
<div class="artist_thumb">
    <div class="artist_thumb_img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">    <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail['url'] ?>"/></a></div>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
```